# изменение данных в сессиях ( $_SESSION ) в php

Tags: php, mysql

Возник следующий вопрос, когда я работаю на сервере с $_SESSION['A'], и одновременно со мной с ней работает еще один пользователь будем ли мы мешать другу другу? Например, я меняю $_SESSION['A'] с 0 на 1, изменится ли она у другого пользователя?

Comment: У другого пользователя будет другая сессия.

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо, если хотите, можете полноценный ответ написать, я отмечу=)